# Jquery filter doesn't work in internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, internet-explorer, filter

This code works fine in chrome, firefox and internet explorer 11. But it has to work in internet explorer 9. I can't see the filter field and the lay out of the page isn't using jquery.

```
<html>
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />    
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>phone numbers</title>
</head>
<body>
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM numbers ORDER BY first name') or die ("Fout: ".mysql_error());

if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
         echo 'no numbers found';
    } else {

    echo '<div id="list" class="marge"><ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search" data-inset="true">';    
        echo '<table class="headers"><tr><td class="table">first name</td><td class="table">last name</td><td class="table">external number</td><td class="table">internal number</td><td class="table">phone number</td><td class="table">shortened phone number</td><td class="table">service number</td><td class="table">location</td></tr></table>';     
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo '<li data-icon="false"><a href="#"><table><tr><td class="table">'.$row['first name'].'</td><td class="table">'.$row['last name'].'</td><td class="table">'.$row['external'].'</td><td class="table">'.$row['internal'].'</td><td class="table">'.$row['phone'].'</td><td class="table">'.$row['shortphone'].'</td><td class="table">'.$row['service'].'</td><td class="table">'.$row['location'].'</td></tr></table></a></li>';                
     }
     echo '</ul></div>'; 

    }

    echo '</body>
</html>';

?>
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with javascript? I can't see any javascript code.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, there was javascript in the source but it wasn't important for my question.